# Artefacts on OpenGL rendering seemingly specific to hardware

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am currently writing a graphics engine for OpenGL in C++. Here's the source if you're interested: https://github.com/freddycansic/OpenGL

---

These are the results when rendering a cube with a solid colour or a texture on my laptop (Ryzen 5500U, integrated Radeon graphics):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKqYJ.jpg

These are the results when rendering the same on my desktop (Ryzen 5 2400G, NVIDIA 1060):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG97j.jpg

As you can see artefacts begin appearing when rendering using a solid colour on my desktop.

---

When rendering more than 1 texture I run into more issues:

Laptop working as normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN9a0.jpg

Desktop 2 textures merging together?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oPj6.jpg

---

The general code for reproducing this is as follows

Shader code:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core  

layout(location = 0) in vec4 a_Position;  
layout(location = 1) in vec4 a_Color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 a_TexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in float a_TexID;

out vec4 v_Color;
out vec2 v_TexCoord;
out float v_TexID;

uniform mat4 u_ViewProj;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_ViewProj * a_Position;  

    v_Color = a_Color;
    v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    v_TexID = a_TexID;
};
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core  

out vec4 color;

in vec4 v_Color;
in vec2 v_TexCoord;
in float v_TexID;

uniform sampler2D u_Textures[32];

void main() {  

    int index = int(v_TexID);

    if (index < 0) { // if index < 0 do a color
        color = v_Color;
    }
    else { // else do a texture
        color = texture(u_Textures[index], v_TexCoord);
    }

};
```

Create vertex array, shader, allocate memory for vertex buffer and index buffer

```
unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();

unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, nullptr);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

// same with fragment

glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(program);
glValidateProgram(program);

glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

unsigned int vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

unsigned int vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 50000 * sizeof(Vertex), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

unsigned int ibo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 75000 * sizeof(GLuint), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Enable vertex attributes for position, colour, texture coordinates and texture ID.

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 40, (const void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 40, (const void*)12);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 40, (const void*)28);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 40, (const void*)36);
```

Now generate vertices and indices for a cube which end up as follows:

Texture ID of `-1` denotes that we are not using a texture.

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, -1}
// ... ommited for sanity
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, -1}

0, 1, 2,
// ...
6, 7, 4
```

These vertices and indices are then stored in separate vectors on the CPU until the batch concludes when:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertex) * CPUVertexBuffer.size(), CPUVertexBuffer.data());

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLuint) * CPUIndexBuffer.size(), CPUIndexBuffer.data());

glUseProgram(program);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) CPUIndexBuffer.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
```

---

If anyone has seen anything like this before or knows of any reason that would be causing this I would love to hear from you.

Comment: You must add the code to the question. Links to external resources tend to break and may not be available in the future and the content may change. Please [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The question is not about my code itself, it's about why my code produces different results on different hardware. My project is also highly abstracted so the underlying OpenGL calls are buried deep but I will try to dig them out and add them to the question.

Comment: The question refers to the code and the code must be added to the question. If you fix the bug in your repository, the problem can no longer be reproduced and the question is useless for others.

Comment: I've added the code, hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: Just from the visuals it looks like you are trying to render something that's exactly the border between two different colours (whatever that means, depending on your fragment shader which you have not shown) and rounding errors are causing it to go in one direction or the other. There was a similar question recently where someone rendered two different textures, selected the texture by rounding float to int, and the float was exactly 1.0.

Comment: I am rounding a float to an int in order to use it as an index into a sampler2D array. I've added the shader source code as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int index = int(v_TexID);
>
> if (index < 0) { // if index < 0 do a color
>     color = v_Color;
> }
> else { // else do a texture
>     color = texture(u_Textures[index], v_TexCoord);
> }
> ```

This code is wrong in two ways. The [GLSL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.htm) clearly states in section 4.1.7:

> Texture-combined sampler types are opaque types, declared and behaving
> as described above for opaque types. **When aggregated into arrays
> within a shader, they can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform
> integral expression, otherwise results are undefined.**

Within the rules of the GLSL spec, a single invocation group can be as big as the whole render API call, so unless your `a_TexID` value isn't the same for all vertices in that render call, the results of this are undefined.

Furthermore, from section 8.1:

> Some texture functions (non-“Lod” and non-“Grad” versions) may require
> implicit derivatives. Implicit derivatives are undefined within
> non-uniform control flow and for non-fragment shader texture fetches.

Since your `texture` call uses implicit derivatives, it must not be used in non-uniform control flow.

What you're trying to do here cannot be achieved within the guarantees of OpenGL 4.6.

What you could do is:

- Don't use an array of `sampler2D`s, use a single `sampler2Darray` with an [array texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture). Selecting the layer from the array doen't have to be a dynamically uniform expression.
- Use the [`GL_ARB_bindless_textures` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_bindless_texture.txt), which also removes this restriction.

Comment: Another possibility (if the range of possible values for v_TexID is not too large) is to sample from all the textures for all possible values of v_TexID, store the results into an array of vec4's, and then select from the array using v_TexID as the index. Of course, if you have more than a few possible id's, this becomes cost prohibitive due to the number of texture fetches.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the proper way to go about this, I will implement it in the future. As helpful as your answer is my initial question still remains. Why does this code produce different results on different hardware? Also what is an implicit derivative?

Comment: @FreddyCansick: It produces different results on different hardware (anbd possibly on the same hardware as well) exactly because the behavior of this code is _undefined_. That's what _undefined_ basically means here. In the HW level, this will largely depend on how the work is scheduled to different invocation groups.

Comment: @FreddyCansick an implicit derivate in this case are the screen space tex coord derivatives the GPU will calculate behind your back to get texture minification/magnification and LOD selection right, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52977548/2327517) for the details.